# How to delete cookies from WKHttpCookieStore?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, wkwebview, ios11

iOS 11 brings some updates for WKWebView including cookies managment. I've started migrating my app from UIWebView and ran into a problem: even though WKHttpCookieStore provides a method for deleting cookies ([deleteCookie:completionHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkhttpcookiestore/2882009-deletecookie), Xamarin wrapper: [DeleteCookieAsync](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/WebKit.WKHttpCookieStore.DeleteCookieAsync/p/Foundation.NSHttpCookie/)), in fact ***it doesn't delete all cookies***. Here is my code:

```
WKHttpCookieStore cookieStore = WKWebsiteDataStore.DefaultDataStore.HttpCookieStore;

// Delete all cookies
NSHttpCookie[] allCookies = await cookieStore.GetAllCookiesAsync();
foreach (NSHttpCookie cookieToDelete in allCookies)
{
    await cookieStore.DeleteCookieAsync(cookieToDelete);
}

NSHttpCookie[] newCookies = await cookieStore.GetAllCookiesAsync();
// why newCookies is not an empty array?

myWkWebView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl("https://facebook.com/")));
```

For example, this cookie is being deleted:

```
NSHTTPCookie    
version:1   
name:c_user     
value:100015842...  
expiresDate:'2017-12-27 07:37:39 +0000'     
created:'2017-09-28 07:39:01 +0000'     
sessionOnly:FALSE   
domain:.facebook.com    
partition:none  
path:/  
isSecure:TRUE  
path:"/" 
isSecure:TRUE
```

But this one isn't:

```
NSHTTPCookie    
version:1   
name:sb     
value:bKbMW......OJ1V   
expiresDate:'2019-09-28 07:37:39 +0000'     
created:'2017-09-28 07:39:15 +0000'     
sessionOnly:FALSE   
domain:.facebook.com    
partition:none  
path:/  
isSecure:TRUE  
path:"/" 
isSecure:TRUE
```

Same problem with native Swift app. I'm quite confused since similar code works just fine with `NSHttpCookieStorage` + `UIWebView`.

Is this expected behavior? If so, why? Is there a way to clean cookies in `WKHttpCookieStore`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: Previously I filled a bugreport at [bugreport.apple.com](https://bugreport.apple.com/) and now I can confirm this is fixed in iOS 12.

---

I jumped to conclusion that it's an iOS bug. So, instead of *deleting* cookies now I'm *replacing* them with cookies with an empty value:

```
NSDictionary properties = NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys(
    objects: new NSObject[] 
    {
        new NSString(cookieToDelete.Name ?? ""),
        new NSString(""),
        new NSString(cookieToDelete.Path ?? ""),
        new NSString(cookieToDelete.Domain ?? ""),
    },
    keys: new NSObject[]    
    { 
        NSHttpCookie.KeyName,
        NSHttpCookie.KeyValue,
        NSHttpCookie.KeyPath,
        NSHttpCookie.KeyDomain,
    }
);
NSHttpCookie cookieToReplace = NSHttpCookie.CookieFromProperties(properties);
await cookieStore.SetCookieAsync(cookieToReplace);
```

Comment: You do not have to "replace" them, just delete them as my code example does (just do **not** use a foreach enumerator)

Comment: @SushiHangover I've tried simple `for`: no difference, the same bugly behavior.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to delete all cookies, then it is easier to do that on the `WKWebsiteDataStore`. In Objective-C:

```
NSSet *websiteDataTypes = [NSSet setWithArray:@[WKWebsiteDataTypeCookies]];
NSDate *dateFrom = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:0];
[[WKWebsiteDataStore defaultDataStore] removeDataOfTypes:websiteDataTypes 
                                           modifiedSince:dateFrom 
                                       completionHandler:nil];
```

Note that this works from iOS 9 onwards.

Comment: Thanks, good point. However deleting cookies of a specific domain is also important for me. I have to check _deleting_ from `HttpCookieStore` on iOS 11.2, maybe now it's fixed...

Answer (score 1):

Stay away from deleting within the enumerator, you will not get any errors, BUT the cookies that are deleted is really random, some session-based, some transient-based will not be deleted.

I have not searched the iOS `radrs`, but one should be opened if there is not as this is an iOS 11 issue (not an Xamarin one) as "most" iOS Framework enumeration return a mutable copy that you can delete within. Otherwise the DeleteCookie(Async) should return an `NSError`...

My Cookie Monster routine:

```
var cookies = await WKWebsiteDataStore.DefaultDataStore.HttpCookieStore.GetAllCookiesAsync();
for (int i = cookies.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    await WKWebsiteDataStore.DefaultDataStore.HttpCookieStore.DeleteCookieAsync(cookies[i]);
}
cookies = await WKWebsiteDataStore.DefaultDataStore.HttpCookieStore.GetAllCookiesAsync();
if (cookies.Length == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Cookie Monster ate them all");
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it looks like an iOS bug.

Comment: Is not working for me. I have tried a lot of workarounds and still not having the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

did you try using `NSHTTPCookieStorage` insted? They should be linked, so changing the NSHTTPCookieStorage should be reflect to WKCookieStorage

Comment: TBH I didn't try, however `NSHTTPCookieStorage` and `WKWebView` are not connected on iOS 10 at least. Are there some changes starting iOS 11?

Comment: hmm, by my experience in iOS11 (didn't test in 10 yet), cookies from WKWebView will reflect to NSHTTPCookieStorage, as a cookie set from the webpage will be after a short delay available in NSHTTPCookieStorage cookies

Comment: Oh, my first comment is wrong, they are connected. I remember why I couldn't use `NSHTTPCookieStorage` in my app : _WKWebView probably syncs cookies back to the UI process on its own schedule. Not after each navigation._  https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=140191 In my case this delay wasn't short and it was unacceptable in the app since the app must react immediately when user logs in.